# Why is ProcessorArchitecture set to None in a loaded assembly

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Some assemblies when loaded have AssemblyName with ProcessorArchitecture set to None. There was a similar post before but it assumed an assembly from GetReferencedAssemblies() where such assembly is not loaded yet and ProcessorArchitecture is simply set to default value. My question refers to the same ProcessorArchitecture but when its value is checked after such assembly is loaded. Very few assemblies show ProcessorArchitecture set to None. On my laptop, GAC has about 800 assemblies and only 7 show ProcessorArchitecture set to None and they are: adodb, Extensibility, Microsoft.mshtml, Microsoft.StdFormat, mscomctl, MSDATASRC,  stdole. 
All seven assemblies have the save values for these two fields:

```
 Magic number in PE Header: 0x10B (32-bit)
 Corflags in CLR Header: 0x09 (ILOnly, StrongNameSigned)
```

Many other assemblies have the same values but all show ProcessorArchitecture set to MSIL. So what are other parameters that determine ProcessorArchitecture? I assumed that the loader determines ProcessorArchitecture only on the basis of these two fields.

Comment: They are ancient PIAs from the .NET 1.0 era, interop assemblies for olden COM components.  ProcessorArchitecture only became relevant at .NET 2.0.  Also visible from their version number, Microsoft still used VS version numbers back then.  7.0.3300.0 was VS2002.

Comment: So how does the loader set the ProcessorArchitecture? This is not something included in assembly and it has to be computed by the loader. Many of so called reference assemblies compiled for the current runtime v4.0.30319 have also ProcessorArchitecture set to None. They tend to include ReferenceAssemblyAttribute but there are assemblies with this attribute that have  ProcessorArchitecture set to MSIL. There are assemblies compiled for v4.0.30319 without ReferenceAssemblyAttribute and still have ProcessorArchitecture set to None.